# Why is my MessageToMessage Encoder not sending data? (Netty 4)

Tags: java, tcp, netty

```
    @Override
protected void encode(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ServerEvent msg, List<Object> out) throws Exception
{
    ByteBuf data = ctx.alloc().buffer();
    msg.encode(data);
    out.add(data);
}
```

The above method lives inside of a MessageToMessage encoder. The server event simply takes a Bytebuf and writes data in the appropriate order for the event.

My client is never receiving this message. I have this encoder in my pipeline and I hit my breakpoints inside of this handler. What am I doing wrong or missing?

Comment: Did you try to add a LoggingHandler in the beginning of your pipeline to see what is actually being written/read? If the client is also a Netty application, you can do the same to the client. If not, try to use the packet dumper like Wireshark.

Comment: The client recieves 0x00000000 (Null). The encoder correctly sends out the correct byte array.

Comment: Are you sure you call flush ?

Comment: Well, out does this automatically, but I have since tried dropping out.add in favor of ctx.writeAndFlush.

I was about to post code to show what I am talking about and I think I just realized the problem. Let me check it when I get off work and I will update this.

Comment: Looked it over some more and turns out I was wrong. Here is what I have currently after playing with it over the weekend.

https://gist.github.com/Sinistralis/8c4e7de6f144aa214d3b

Content is correctly filled the the byte array from the buffer. I can verify that.

Comment: How you write the data ? I mean what method you call on Channel or ChannelHandlerContext to write your pojo.

Comment: It's in the gist above. I convert the object to a binary array and pass it through ctx.writeAndFlush()

Comment: This only shows what you do in the encoder itself. I was more interested to see how you write the ServerEvent itself

Comment: The server event is nothing more than a struct for data that loads it into a ByteBuf in a specific order.

Anything that implements ServerEvent basically holds data, and performs ByteBuf.write(variable) in the specific order I expect. I can then manipulate the ByteBuf however I want from there and know the data is correctly constructed. https://gist.github.com/Sinistralis/986ddbc7cbc45eb1cf42